# scala -- handling nested json and missing fileds

Tags: json, scala

I am looking to process the json file as below

```
{
    "fixed": "abc",
    "issues": [{
        "issue": "issue0",
        "fields": {
            "value": "value1"
        }
    }, {
        "issue": "issue1",
        "fields": {
            "value": "value2"
        }
    }]
}
```

I am looking to explode the json. Which I can do in lot of way. 
I am looking for ways to deal with missing json fields.

For example, I need to query for field "nonexistingcolumn" which may exist in some json files and may not in another.

The output should be tabular and something like below.

```
fixed |  issue |  value | nonexitingcolumn
abc   | issue0 | value1 | null
abc   | issue1 | value2 | null
```

Update: 
nonexistingcolumn is part of nested json as ex: "issues.fields.name".

Comment: hi can you please give an example of nonexistingcolumn

Comment: Hi Raj ..just updated the post .. it will be part of nested json as "issues.fields.name". We need handle a case where this field does not exist in an instance of Json file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution consists of several steps:

1. Parsing json to some model object.
2. Building a table
3. (optional) Console output of the table

1st step could be accomplished by [play-json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json) library:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7"
```

The library allows to auto-generate formatters which facilitate parsing json to a corresponding Scala class. Probably the same could be accomplished by other json libraries as well.

2st and 3rd steps are technical. A key thing is that we model "fields" object as a Map[String, String].

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(
    """
  {
    "fixed": "abc",
    "issues": [{
    "issue": "issue0",
    "fields": {
      "value": "value1"
    }
  }, {
    "issue": "issue1",
    "fields": {
      "value": "value2",
      "nonexistingcolumn": "blabla"
    }
  }]
  }""")

  case class Issue(issue: String, fields: Map[String, String])
  case class Model(fixed: String, issues: List[Issue])

  implicit val issueFormat = Json.format[Issue]
  implicit val modelFormat = Json.format[Model]

  val model = json.as[Model]

  val fieldNames = (for {
    issue <- model.issues
    field <- issue.fields
  } yield field._1) distinct

  val table = model.issues map { issue =>
    model.fixed :: issue.issue :: (fieldNames map { fieldName =>
      issue.fields.getOrElse(fieldName, "null")
    })
  }

  val headers = (List("fixed", "issue") ++ fieldNames)
  val tableWithHeaders =  headers :: table

  tableWithHeaders foreach { row =>
    println(row map (" %-20s ".format(_)) mkString("|"))
  }
```